# combining tempfile and tarfile with python?

Tags: python, zip, temporary-files, tarfile

say we have a tempfile to which we could write some output. but for some strange reason we want it to be compressed by some of archiving techniques, tar for instance,

by tempfile I mean the one which has not visiable name created by tempfile.TemporaryFile().
any ideas?
my first impression includes some tweeking and class inheritance..
are there any simpler ways?

Comment: search doc for `tempfile`, `tarfile`, and you will find many well working options even on standard Python library. In your question it is not clear, if you ask for using `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` or you want prevent using it.

Comment: true it is not clear enough, I mainly want to create compressed  (hash-a'like) content and store it temporarily inside a file created by tempfile.TemporaryFile(),  :)

Comment: this content could be a source code, got by introspecting actual working a archiving program using inspect method,

Comment: btw - `tar` is not compressing on its own. But with options like "tar.gz", "tar.bz2" it serves very well.

Answer (score 5):

The `fileobj` argument of [`tarfile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) serves exactly this purpose: you can pass any file-like object that support writting to it and `tarfile` will happily use that instead of trying to reach out to the filesystem. Note that such files should be opened in binary mode and not in text mode (which `tempfile.TemporaryFile` does by default).

Similarly, the first argument to [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) can be a file-like object.

So you could do:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix='.tar.gz') as f:
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='w:gz') as tar:
        tar.add(…)

    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```

Or

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('wb', suffix='.tar.gz', delete=False) as f:
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='w:gz') as tar:
        tar.add(…)
```

to keep `f.name` on your filesystem and explore its content later.